# javascript objects alternative syntax

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, photoshop

I have just started scripting for photoshop using javascript

A simple piece of script is

```
var textItemRef = artLayerRef.textItem 
textItemRef.contents = "Hello World"
```

I understand that `artLayerRef.textItem`  is a class and object of that class
and that `textItemRef.contents` is an object and property of that object.

However I am used to using javascript for webpage
so an object might be a div
and its property would be innerHTML

I would write that like this

```
var A = document.getElementbyID('div id'); var A.InnerHTML = hello
world.
```

How would I access a DIV object using the same style of code as shown in the Photoshop example - ie without the `getElementbyID('div id')`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: There are no classes in JS.

Answer (score 0):

you definetely can do it

```
var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');
d.innerHTML = 'test';
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2KRxp/)

1. don't use spaces in div's id
2. you don't need to write `var` every line, `A` is already your part of DOM

On a webpage you deal with DOM through [document](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp). You can access its' [elements](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) using [getElementById()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp), [getElementsByName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp), [getElementsByTagName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp) or even  [document.forms](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp) (all forms on page) and [document.images](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_images.asp) (all images)

After that you can access all their properties, use methods, bind [events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) and even create your own stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Using the DOM and one of the `getElement*` methods like you've described is the right way to get a handle on an element to then manipulate it further.